# How many beats/counts does this note get in 3/4 time?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures

[image: what note is this]   image link down below

please tell me the counts so I can know how to do it

Answer (score 4):

Let us break this down. When we are counting 16th notes out loud, it is pretty common musicians to count it as '1' 'ee' 'and' 'a' as we see in this image. [image]

And since we know that two 16ths = 1 eighth, we can count the rhythm like this (Note, you do not play any new notes on 'and':

[image]

If you want to hear how the rhythm sounds it sounds like [this.](https://stringquest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sixteentheighthsixteenth.mp3)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 notes there and they all fit into one beat.

If you know "Hang down your head, Tom Dooley" just sing "Hang down your". That's the rhythm.

Or...

While counting "**1** 2 3 4 **1** 2 3 4 **1** 2 3 4" out loud, clap on the 1, 2 and 4.

When that has become easy, keep clapping but only say the "1"s: "1...1...1..."

When that has become easy, keep clapping but instead of "1...1...1..." say "A...B...C..."

When that has become easy, keep clapping but instead of "A...B...C..." say "1...2...3..."

Now you are clapping the right rhythm and counting the beats of the 3/4 bar.

It could have been written like the first bar below but it's standard practice to join the notes under a single beam. In other words, these two sound identical:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a syncopation: counting the shortest, there are 3 notes on 4 beats, the middle note has the double length as the others.

**The accent is always on the first note!**